# Deserialize/serialize array of "any Type" elements

Tags: c#, xml, serialization

I have the following XML of elements:

```xml
<FieldValues>
    <anyType xsi:type="xsd:string" />
    <anyType xsi:type="xsd:string" />
    <anyType xsi:type="xsd:string" />
    <anyType xsi:type="xsd:string" />
    <anyType xsi:type="xsd:string" />
    <anyType xsi:type="xsd:string" />
    <anyType xsi:type="xsd:string" />
</FieldValues>
```

in order to deserialze it, I am using:

```cs
[XmlArrayItem("anyType", IsNullable = true)]
public string[] FieldValues
{
    get; set;
}
```

the problem is that after serialization instead of getting this:

```xml
<FieldValues>
    <anyType xsi:type="xsd:string" />
    <anyType xsi:type="xsd:string" />
    <anyType xsi:type="xsd:string" />
    <anyType xsi:type="xsd:string" />
    <anyType xsi:type="xsd:string" />
    <anyType xsi:type="xsd:string" />
    <anyType xsi:type="xsd:string" />
</FieldValues>
```

I am getting this:

```xml
<FieldValues>
    <anyType />
    <anyType />
    <anyType />
    <anyType />
    <anyType />
    <anyType />
    <anyType />
</FieldValues>
```

I can't see the attribute, `xsi:type="xsd:string"`
any thought why?

Comment: Could you please share with us the deserializer and serializer code?

Comment: I think you might need to use [`XmlIncludeAttribute`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.xml.serialization.xmlincludeattribute).